# Same PNG causing two different images

Tags: google-chrome, animation, binary, png, apng

I found an image (png) which is able to change it's content "dramatically" and I wonder how this works:

**This is how the image looks like in Windows:**

[image: How it appears in Windows]

**This is how the image looks like in Chrome:**

[[image: How it appears in Chrome[2]]

**Original Image:**

[image: Original Image (Could looks strangely)]

*About the source of the image: I found this image in the Discord Server of "Starcraft 2 AI". The poster claims not to be the owner and not to know the owner.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming.

Comment: @JoshLee Thank you, I've upvoted your answer/comment. It is an animated PNG.

Comment: This is largely the generic text of a close reason. And yes, we do generally inform users why a question is closed. If it is not about programming, it is off topic on SO. It might be on topic on e.g. SuperUser, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Technically the question is still valid: Even in Electron (Discord is build on top of Electron) the image is shown like in version 1, but on Chrome (which uses Electron too) it shows the second version of the image. Don't you think it's worth to know what causes this?